# Block relation with specific domain in wordpress

Tags: plugins, functions

I am facing an issue of redirect and the cause is a js file being load from 3rd party domain name.

the script is added to almost 50% of my JavaScript that includes a Javascript file in header of my wordpress the JavaScript file is located in "sarcoma[dot]space/js/main.min.js".

I want to block the domain so my wordpress shouldn't get any input from that file/domain. How I can do this.

"My website got hacked 2 months after the installation of Malcare plugin"

I've removed the plugin and deleted its all files and change the rules did everything but I can't change those 50% JavaScript files.

I've cleaned the website but the 50% JS files are still infected.

Comment: Blocking the domain will increase overall response time and isn't the ideal solution here. Do a string search for that domain in all files and database in your WordPress installation. You may have to download the files and database in your local machine and use a code editor like Notepad++ for that.